# 'Jump starting' Power-One Server Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, power

Which pins have to be shorted for this to start?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: i took the liberty to fix your question ... `does anybody know ...?` is not a question about the power supply

Answer (score 1):

From the [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Power%20One%20PDFs/PALS_Series.pdf): VO1 and VO2 ENA have to be pulled to ground to enable the respective outputs.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't search the datasheet, thank you very much

Comment: I only need the 12v where do you think Vo2 ENA should go? psup, vaux RNT, vo2-s, Vo2CS?

Comment: I would try VO2 RTN.

Comment: Vaux RTN works great

Comment: thanks again vir